# How to fetch data from Database and sort them using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need to fetch data from database and sort them according to column value using PHP and MySQL.I am explaining the scenario below.

> db_users:(table name)

```
id     user_name    user_type
1       usr1           1

2       user2          1

3       user3          2

4       user4          2

5       user5          3

6       user6          3

7       user7          4

8       user8          4
```

My table name is given above.

Here i need first i will fetch all data and i should get the data in array format which is given below.

```
$values=array('member'=>$member_type,'no_of_member'=>2) 
print json_encode($values);
```

Here condition is when `user_type==1` the `$member_type` should be `member1` and `no_of_member` will be how many numbers of member1(in this case it is 2).So like this all data should set accordingly(`for user_type 2 it should member2 and so on...`).Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php/17364128#17364128

Comment: i am confused of this page.

Comment: in "function cmp" on that page that I linked, replace ['foo'] with ['no_of_member']

Comment: @RichardTheobald : Still i am little bit confused..Can you please write your idea here.

Comment: Try this query - SELECT user_type as member, count(*) as no_of_members FROM `db_users` GROUP BY user_type